# How do I print a Celsius symbol with matplotlib?

Tags: python, unicode, latex, matplotlib

I want to print an axis label: "Temperature (℃)". How do I do it?
A snippet is this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(10,60,1)
y = range(-100, 0, 2)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xlabel('Temperature (℃)')
```

For that last line I have tried:

```
ax.set_xlabel('Temperature (℃)'.encode('utf-8'))

ax.set_xlabel(u'Temperature (u\2103)')

ax.set_xlabel(u'Temperature (℃)')

ax.set_xlabel(u'Temperature (\u2103)')

ax.set_xlabel('Temperature (\u2103)')
```

I just don't get it. I'm using spyder and running the code from there.

Comment: Does your code work if run from as script outside of spyder?

Comment: Ahh, I did try that out initially, but got the same result as running it from spyder (must have been an incorrect formulation anyway). I should have tried again with a few of the others I listed above.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the LaTeX interpreter to make the degree symbol.

```
ax.set_xlabel('Temperature ($^\circ$C)')
```

Here's the results:

[image]

Comment: I think this is the best solution for me. It also has the advantage of making my figure labels match my text (I use LaTeX for typesetting). Instead of $^\circ$C, I used \textcelsius.

Answer (score 8):

```
ax.set_xlabel(u'Temperature (℃)')
```

should work:

[image]

```
In [56]: matplotlib.__version__
Out[56]: '1.0.1'
```

Comment: Seems spyder doesn't support utf-8. I can't even enter utf-8 characters using the "Ctrl+Shift+U" compose key method. spyder's editor just ignores it and enters a 'U'. I was copying the celsius symbol across from gnome's character map application.

Answer (score 8):

To make this work in matplotlib without the LaTex interpreter, use unicode formatting **AND** the unicode character string

```
from numpy import arange, cos, pi
from matplotlib.pyplot import (figure, axes, plot, xlabel, ylabel, title,
                               grid, show)
figure(1, figsize=(6,4))
ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.7])
t = arange(0.0, 1.0 + 0.01, 0.01)
s = 3*cos(2*pi*t)+25
plot(t, s)

title('Average High Temperature')
xlabel('Year')
ylabel(u'Temp (\u00B0C)')
grid(True)
show()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks the best IMO; the LaTeX $\circ$ circle is way too small.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of DEGREE CELSIUS U+2103 (℃), use the DEGREE SIGN U+00B0 (°) followed by the capital letter. This is much safer for several reasons, including font coverage. It is also the way recommended in the [Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/) (15.2 Letterlike symbols; p. 481).

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
ax.set_xlabel(u'Temperature (\N{DEGREE SIGN}C)')
```

If you want to make it compatible to TeX *and* non-TeX, then one probably has to use both ways and test with `if rcParams['text.usetex']` before-hand. This is [how it's done in basemap](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/blob/v1.0.7rel/lib/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py#L5192) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Spyder users:

$^\circ$ - works!

\N{DEGREE SIGN} - gives me the lower case gamma symbol...

Answer (score 0):

Unicode degree sign character is [`U+00B0`](https://symbl.cc/en/00B0), so you can use `\u00b0C` in your string to get `°C`:

```py
ax.set_xlabel('Temperature (\u00b0C)')
```